# VB.NET TableRows.Add only adding row on first call

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am attempting to load 2 rows into a preexisting table when a button is clicked. The first row loads no problem. The second row doesn't show up at all and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I have tried using Table.Row.AddAt getting the index of the last row to override the last row position but that did not work.

Here is the table:

```
<asp:Table ID="ContactTable" GridLines="Both" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="15" CellSpacing="0">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server" ID="ContactHeaderRow" BackColor="LightGray">
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="First Name"></asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Last Name"></asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Email"></asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Active"></asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Address"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableFooterRow runat="server" ID="ContactFooterRow">
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="5">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="NewContactBtn" Text="+" /></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableFooterRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

And here is the code behind. It hides the add button and should display the new rows. The row containing the textboxes for the submission of data and the row containing the submit button:

```
Protected Sub NewContact(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewContactBtn.Click
    Dim dataRow As New TableRow()
    Dim submitRow As New TableRow()
    Dim submitCell As New TableCell() With {.ColumnSpan = 5}
    Dim submitButton As New Button() With {.Text = "Submit"}
    Dim fNameControl As New TableCell()
    Dim lNameControl As New TableCell()
    Dim emailControl As New TableCell()
    Dim addressControl As New TableCell()
    Dim activeControl As New TableCell()
    Dim fNameBox As New TextBox()
    Dim lNameBox As New TextBox()
    Dim emailBox As New TextBox()
    Dim activeCheck As New CheckBox()
    Dim numberBox As New TextBox()
    Dim numberLabel As New Label() With {.Text = "Street Number: "}
    Dim streetBox As New TextBox()
    Dim streetLabel As New Label() With {.Text = "Street Name: "}
    Dim cityBox As New TextBox()
    Dim cityLabel As New Label() With {.Text = "City: "}
    Dim stateBox As New TextBox()
    Dim stateLabel As New Label() With {.Text = "Province/State: "}
    Dim countryBox As New TextBox()
    Dim countryLabel As New Label() With {.Text = "Country: "}
    Dim postalBox As New TextBox()
    Dim postalLabel As New Label() With {.Text = "Postal: "}
    submitCell.Controls.Add(submitButton)
    fNameControl.Controls.Add(fNameBox)
    lNameControl.Controls.Add(lNameBox)
    emailControl.Controls.Add(emailBox)
    activeControl.Controls.Add(activeCheck)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(numberLabel)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(numberBox)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(streetLabel)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(streetBox)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(cityLabel)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(cityBox)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(stateLabel)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(stateBox)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(countryLabel)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(countryBox)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(postalLabel)
    addressControl.Controls.Add(postalBox)
    dataRow.Cells.Add(fNameControl)
    dataRow.Cells.Add(lNameControl)
    dataRow.Cells.Add(emailControl)
    dataRow.Cells.Add(activeControl)
    dataRow.Cells.Add(addressControl)
    ContactFooterRow.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none")
    ContactTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
    ContactTable.Rows.Add(submitRow)
End Sub
```

I am still new to VB.NET so any advice or better practices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear why you have such a boatload of code here?

Also, it not at all clear why you attempting to use a table. Why not use GridView, or some other asp.net control that is data aware.

Worse yet, you don't mention what database you planning to use here?

Just trying to code out some data operations without a database quite much means you going to have to code out the database system!

Now, I 100% grasp, your just learning, so you say, hey, why not try some simple table operations before I REALLY connect up this to a database.

But, then that means you writing a boatload of code for the UI stuff, and at the end of the day, WHEN you finally decide to hook up a database, you wind up tossing out all of your current efforts - for no good end to a means.

A REALLY important tip and concept?

Add the data to the database, and THEN re-load the data to the "user interface". In other words, don't write a boatload of code for the UI side, but think in terms of data operations and THEN pushing that data out to the web page. You save a few keyboards by adopting this way of thinking.

And as noted, little reason to just drop in a table - they don't really have much data binding support - so, once again, you will wear out a keyboard with that choice.

I suggest a gridview, or even better yet is the newer ListView - they are quite much (mostly) just a table layout, but you can use data binding, and automatic shove out data to the listview or gridview.

If you layout becomes complex, then use a listview - it is far more flexible then say a grid view.

As noted, you are making this difficult, since we don't have the database hooked up.

But, we can at least I suppose build a table, and use that table to "drive" this example.

And as a FYI:

I STILL use the wizards to generate the layout. I then REMOVE the datasource from the page, and then remove the datasourceID setting of the listview (or grid view).

At that point, the markup is mostly generated for me.

So, lets lay this out as a gridView.

You get this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="table borderhide" >
              <HeaderStyle CssClass="myHead" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name"><ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email"><ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"><ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Checked ='<%# Eval("Active") %>' ></asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address"><ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>'
                      Textmode="MultiLine" Rows="2">
                </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdNew" runat="server" Text="+" CssClass="btn" />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save Edits" CssClass="btn" style="margin-left:25px" />
```

Now, to load this up with data table, well, as noted, lets just create the table in code.

So, we have this code:

```
Dim rstTable As New DataTable
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        CreateTable()
        GridView1.DataSource = rstTable
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
        rstTable = Session("Table")
    End If

End Sub

Sub CreateTable()

    rstTable.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
    rstTable.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))
    rstTable.Columns.Add("Email", GetType(String))
    rstTable.Columns.Add("Active", GetType(Boolean))
    rstTable.Columns.Add("Address", GetType(String))
    Session("Table") = rstTable

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdNew.Click

    Dim OneRow As DataRow = rstTable.NewRow
    OneRow("FirstName") = "Test first"
    OneRow("Active") = True
    rstTable.Rows.Add(OneRow)

    GridView1.DataSource = rstTable
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And run, we get this:

[image]

If we click on the "+" button, then we have this:

[image]

But, ultimate here, the real goal is what database are we going to use here, since really just a in-memory table don't help a lot - we need to get a database up and running.

but, as you can see, not a whole lot of code, and if you ARE writing a boatload of code? you using the wrong approach - you just are.

Add the data at the data level - then re-send (re-bind) to the display and UI. Don't try and "operate" against the UI part. As you can see, not a lot of code here.
And even the Gridview - we could have had "none" markup, and let it auto generate the table based on the data table we send to the gridview. (however, to be fair, as you pile on more and more fancy layout, then as noted, you want to add + setup markup for the GridView, and in fact, if you get really fancy (combo box, radio buttons, etc)? Then use a Listview, they have far more flexible layout.